# How to approach software quality in a big enterprise project

Tags: test-management, test-planning, planning

We made an action list about where to improve in the enterprise software but we are not sure about where to start. These are the list of things we are going to implement but not sure about the priorities. Any thoughts about how to approach?

The Software Quality Action List

- Centralized Monitoring by using Elastic Search
- Implementing Microservices
- Move to Rich domain model from anemic domain model
- Implement Dependency Inversion
- Implement Aspect oriented programming
- Implement Code Contracts
- Implement Test Automation by unittest integrated to CI

Answer (score 1):

I would rate each of these improvements on 2 dimensions: 
- The impact to quality if it was implemented
- The ease/quickness/cost that the improvement can be implemented

If you have any high impact, easy to do items - those are your first priorities. Otherwise, you might want to take the highest from each category.  (one easy, one high impact)

You probably already have some idea of the improvements that your stakeholders are looking for.  For example: better delivered quality, faster performance, faster/more efficient development cycle, better reliability/availability, etc.   These areas can help you identify which of your ideas will have greater impact.

For example, for better delivered quality, perhaps unit testing would have a high impact.  For better availability, maybe monitoring.

On the cost (or time) to implement, your list looks like its mostly filled with ideas for new development, or lots of rework. The monitoring idea could be put in place without developing new code.

Good luck,

John